# Can only pick up the first record under tag from xml variable

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'd appreciate someone helping me with this.  Sometimes I  get the same id in all the results and I can never get the 2nd record (graduation), just the 1st.

xml format is the following: record tags can contain one or more DOCTORAL tags:

```
    <Record username=<"erttt">
      <DOCTORAL>
        <PROGRAM>Program Name 1</PROGRAM>
        <MILESTONE>Entered Program</MILESTONE>
        <DTM_DATE>August</DTM_DATE>
        <DTD_DATE>24</DTD_DATE>
        <DTY_DATE>2015</DTY_DATE>
      </DOCTORAL>
   </Record>
   <Record> username=<"xxxgh">
      <DOCTORAL>
         <PROGRAM>Program Name 2</PROGRAM>
         <MILESTONE>Entered Program</MILESTONE>
         <DTM_DATE>Jan</DTM_DATE>
         <DTD_DATE>2</DTD_DATE>
         <DTY_DATE>2014</DTY_DATE>
     </DOCTORAL>
     <DOCTORAL>
         <PROGRAM>Program Name 2</PROGRAM>
         <MILESTONE>Graduated</MILESTONE>
         <DTM_DATE>August</DTM_DATE>
         <DTD_DATE>26</DTD_DATE>
         <DTY_DATE>2016</DTY_DATE>
     </DOCTORAL>
  </Record>
```

I want to get result like:

```
    username  Program           Milestone         
    erttt     Program Name 1    Entered Program    
    xxxgh     Program Name 2    Entered Program     
    xxxgh     Program Name 2    Graduated
```

so, there would be 3 records from the above.

The following is not working, and I have tried many different combinations and looked at examples on this site.  Just can't figure it out...

```sql
SELECT
     x.value('(//Record/@username)[1]','varchar(50)') AS username, --'@username','varchar(50)' DOESN'T WORK HERE
     c.value('(//Record/DOCTORAL/PROGRAM)[1]','varchar(200)') as PROGRAM, 
    c.value('(//Record/DOCTORAL/MILESTONE)[1]','varchar(50)') as MILESTONE,
    c.value('(//Record/DOCTORAL/DTM_DATE)[1]','varchar(8)') as DTM_DATE, --DTM_DATE
    c.value('(//Record/DOCTORAL/DTD_DATE)[1]','varchar(2)') as DTD_DATE,  --DTD_DATE
    c.value('(//Record/DOCTORAL/DTY_DATE)[1]','varchar(4)') as DTY_DATE  --DTY_DATE 
from @xmlDocPrelim.nodes('//Record') t(x)  -- if ends with 'Record', then same id in all recs; if ends in DOCTORAL, then not.  In either case, no grad recs
  cross apply  x.nodes('./DOCTORAL')r(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are syntax errors in your XML. After fix the following code gives what you want.

```
declare @x xml=
'<Record username="erttt">
      <DOCTORAL>
        <PROGRAM>Program Name 1</PROGRAM>
        <MILESTONE>Entered Program</MILESTONE>
        <DTM_DATE>August</DTM_DATE>
        <DTD_DATE>24</DTD_DATE>
        <DTY_DATE>2015</DTY_DATE>
      </DOCTORAL>
   </Record>
   <Record username="xxxgh">
      <DOCTORAL>
         <PROGRAM>Program Name 2</PROGRAM>
         <MILESTONE>Entered Program</MILESTONE>
         <DTM_DATE>Jan</DTM_DATE>
         <DTD_DATE>2</DTD_DATE>
         <DTY_DATE>2014</DTY_DATE>
     </DOCTORAL>
     <DOCTORAL>
         <PROGRAM>Program Name 2</PROGRAM>
         <MILESTONE>Graduated</MILESTONE>
         <DTM_DATE>August</DTM_DATE>
         <DTD_DATE>26</DTD_DATE>
         <DTY_DATE>2016</DTY_DATE>
     </DOCTORAL>
  </Record>'

  select  t.v.value('../@username','varchar(20)') username,
          t.v.value('PROGRAM[1]','varchar(20)') Program,
          t.v.value('MILESTONE[1]','varchar(20)') Milestone
  from @x.nodes('//DOCTORAL') t(v)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I spent way too much time trying to find a solution.

Comment: This is OK, but one hint: With XPath you should be as specific as possible. Using the double slash with `.nodes(//DOCTORAL)` works, but will cost performance and is erronous with bigger structures. I'm dealing with XMLs where you can find identically named elements in different positions... I'd prefer the way @Brian Pressler took with `.nodes` on `Record` and `CROSS APPLY ...nodes` on `DOCTORAL`. Your approach needs more expensive navigation...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the syntax you need:

```
declare @xmlDocPrelim as xml
set @xmlDocPrelim =
'<Record username="erttt">
      <DOCTORAL>
        <PROGRAM>Program Name 1</PROGRAM>
        <MILESTONE>Entered Program</MILESTONE>
        <DTM_DATE>August</DTM_DATE>
        <DTD_DATE>24</DTD_DATE>
        <DTY_DATE>2015</DTY_DATE>
      </DOCTORAL>
   </Record>
   <Record username="xxxgh">
      <DOCTORAL>
         <PROGRAM>Program Name 2</PROGRAM>
         <MILESTONE>Entered Program</MILESTONE>
         <DTM_DATE>Jan</DTM_DATE>
         <DTD_DATE>2</DTD_DATE>
         <DTY_DATE>2014</DTY_DATE>
     </DOCTORAL>
     <DOCTORAL>
         <PROGRAM>Program Name 2</PROGRAM>
         <MILESTONE>Graduated</MILESTONE>
         <DTM_DATE>August</DTM_DATE>
         <DTD_DATE>26</DTD_DATE>
         <DTY_DATE>2016</DTY_DATE>
     </DOCTORAL>
  </Record>
 '
 select @xmlDocPrelim

 SELECT
     x.value('@username','varchar(50)') AS username,
    c.value('./PROGRAM[1]','varchar(200)') as PROGRAM, 
    c.value('./MILESTONE[1]','varchar(50)') as MILESTONE,
    c.value('./DTM_DATE[1]','varchar(8)') as DTM_DATE,
    c.value('(./DTD_DATE)[1]','varchar(2)') as DTD_DATE,
    c.value('(./DTY_DATE)[1]','varchar(4)') as DTY_DATE
from @xmlDocPrelim.nodes('//Record') t(x)
cross apply x.nodes('DOCTORAL') r(c)
```

Results:

```
username   PROGRAM           MILESTONE           DTM_DATE DTD_DATE DTY_DATE
---------- ----------------- ------------------- -------- -------- --------
erttt      Program Name 1    Entered Program     August   24       2015
xxxgh      Program Name 2    Entered Program     Jan      2        2014
xxxgh      Program Name 2    Graduated           August   26       2016
```

Comment: I can't downvote, so entering here that the above does not work.  It was producing same erroneous results.

Comment: Really?  What version of SQL Server are you using; I'm on 2008 r2?  It works fine for me... I added the xml variable that I'm using and my result set to my answer.

Comment: @user3460848, *does not work* is quite meaningless... This works perfectly... Brian, just one hint: You can put it a bit short with `DTD_DATE[1]` instead of `./DTD_DATE[1]` or `(./DTD_DATE)[1]`